# I'm in trouble with my nth-element function in OCaml. I can't find what's wrong

Tags: list, ocaml

the function nth must work like this :

```
# nth [1;2;3;4;5] 0;;
- : int = 1
# nth [1;2;3;4;5] 1;;
- : int = 2
# nth [1;2;3;4;5] 2;;
- : int = 3
# nth [1;2;3;4;5] 3;;
- : int = 4
```

I wrote this function named nth like this :

```
let rec nth l n =
    match l with
    |[] -> raise (Failure "list is too short")
    |hd::tl -> 
    if n > 0 then nth tl n-1 else hd
```

So I typed `nth [1;2;3;4;5] 3` and the expected output was 4 but the console said "list is too short"

My expected algorithm is this :
nth [1;2;3;4;5] 3

```
1::[2;3;4;5] 3 > 0 is true, so nth [2;3;4;5] 2 is called.
2::[3;4;5] 2 > 0 is true, so nth [3;4;5] 1 is called.
3::[4,5] 1 > 0 is true, so nth [4;5] 0 is called
4::[5] 0 > 0 is false, so return 4
so nth [1;2;3;4;5] 3 = 4
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a precedence problem. The expression `nth tl n-1` is parsed like this: `(nth tl n) - 1`. You need parentheses like this: `nth tl (n - 1)`.

If you try your current code with a list of strings (say), you'll get a possibly more helpful error message from the toplevel.

Other than this one problem your code looks excellent btw.

Comment: how does his pattern match handle a list of one element? it looks like it handles the empty list or a list with both a head and tail, thus at least 2 elements. shouldn't there be an extra case in there?

Comment: Note that the tail is a list, not an element. In particular, it can be an empty list. When the tail is `[]`, you have a list of one element.

Comment: Oh of course, I get it. I'm dying to try out the iOS compiler you have experience with, one of these days very soon. I hope it goes smoothly.